# Quotes around $VARIABLE?

Tags: string, variables, csh

What does a line of code like this do?

```
if ("$MY_VARIABLE" == "some_string") ...
```

Is that just how csh interprets variables as strings for comparison and assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes mean that the variable will be expanded as a single argument with spaces intact, rather than broken into multiple pieces at whitespace.